# AWS EC2 instance error with Docker: docker0: port 1(veth3e0f04e) entered disabled state

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

Im running Node app through Docker on my EC2 instance. it's stuck with below logs and I couldn't figure out why it doesnt run my Docker image.

```
      docker0: port 1(veth3e0f04e) entered disabled state
```

This is the AMI name: amzn2-ami-ecs-hvm-2.0.20221230-x86_64-ebs

What might be missing in my setup based on this log?

Does it mean that docker has started?

Am I not able to see docker logs?

Edit: On my inital post error was due to reading issue from S3 bucket. After I fixed that I kept getting the error which is described in the title and shown on screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The `login:` is what a Linux usually shows when it has finished booting up and expects you to log in with a user name and password. Not sure why you expect Docker to start; it is not part of the default Amazon Linux AMI. Can you please add more details about your AMI and the userdata configuration?

Comment: I was able to make ec2 run the docker image but it keeps on crashing now. I have uploaded the docker image through ECR. So I just put the image URI into the task definition and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to spot the exact problem and solve it, thanks to various SO posts.

For those who might have a problem at the early stages of their EC2 deployment, here is step-by-step how I tracked the problem and solved it:

1. Instead of EC2 screenshots or logs I started searching about the error which was given for the `Task Definition`. You can find it under ECS > Clusters > Tasks > Stopped > Last Status.
   My error was: `Essential container in task exited`
2. Which led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55713930/15741905) which explains how to get logs from Docker.
3. Then from the same Stopped tab, I clicked on Task Id > Logs and spotted an error like this: `exec format error`
4. Which led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921165/15741905) and it finally solved my problem.
5. So it turned out that the error was caused because the Docker build on Mac M1 was not suitable with AWS Linux.